# I want to store attendance of the employee in such a way that i can get monthly attendance using firebase database-Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

I am new here I don't know how to post also, but ill explain my requirement

After storing data in firebase database 
I want to get the data in two ways
Date and monthly

Comment: what did you tried so far?? any **`Efforts`** from your side??

Comment: I have stored as  shown in  image...But the problem is I can get day wise report but unable get monthly wise ....In x month how many days employee was present

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get your question right you are able to retrieve the data for each day about employees, but you want to know how many days employees are present per month. maybe like this:

```
     DatabaseReference employees_ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("EmployeesAttendance").child(Employee_uid).child("2018").child("March");

     employees_Ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new Value....{

        onDataChanged(DataSnapshot datasnapshot){

          //get the number of days that employees where present in march
          int number_days_present_march=datasnapshot.getChildrenCount();



         }  


      });
```

**EDIT**

I guess what you want now is to know at when employee x was present and at when he/she left (or became absent).

For that you have to get at each day that you want when he/she was here and when they left.

- example:

lets say I want to know when did employee x come and when did he leave at 2018/march/18:

```
   //get a reference of employee x during 2018/march/18
   Databasereference employee_presence= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("EmployeesAttendance").child(EmployeeX_uid).child("2018").child("march").child("18");

  //use the reference to know when he was in and when he was out

   employee_presence.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new Value.....{

    onDatachange(DataSnapshot datasnapshot){

     //if you stored your date as number (long)
     //get the presence like this:

     long time_in=datasnapshot.child("in_time").getValue(long.class);

     long time_out=datasnapshot.child("out_time").getValue(long.class);

     //show a message

     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Employee X was in at"+ String.Valueof(time_in) + "and was out at" + String.Valueof(time_out) ).show();


     //if you stored your date as a string
     //get the presence like this:

     String time_in= datasnapshot.child("time_in").getValue().toString();

     String time_out= datasnapshot.child("time_out").getValue().toString();


      //show a message
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Employee x was in at" +  time_in + "and was out at" + time_out).show();



    }

   });
```

Comment: thanks for the solution.....and i need one more help svi.data
From above image
i need to compare the sub node of Date status="present / absent".
is it possible ?

Comment: @Rajkiran check my EDIT. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot man ....really ur helping me a lot ......i need your help i dnt know how to post here i am new to android ..please watsapp me 9550534541..i have few dbouts

Comment: Do you know how we can convert firebase timestamp into our normal date or vice versa

Comment: @Rajkiran you will have to look that up on google ..... I am sure this was posted on stack overflow. GoodLuck.